# Removal of ¶ (pilcrow) from pasted text

Tags: vba, string, text, character-encoding, carriage-return

Users are pasting text from Lotus Notes into my VBA application.  This is then being stored in Access.  Sometimes the pasted text includes what I assume is a carriage return which, when pasted into a single line form control, is displayed in the application's forms as ¶.

However, as this won't paste in to the VBE, I am unable to add this to my list of illegal characters for SQL transactions.  I have tried trapping `Chr(10)`, `Chr(13)` and even the pilcrow symbol `Chr(182)`, but nothing will allow detection and removal of this character.

Other than this the symbol causes no problems, it's just a display thing.

Is there any way I can detect this character and strip it from a string?

Edit: I've done some testing and got the application to tell me what the character code of the rightmost character is and it confirms it to be `Chr(10)` - will try a different tack and handle this as an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handled this as an exception to the normal string cleansing and just trimmed the CR/LF off any strings.  Simpler than I thought in the end, but it did have me stumped for a while.